System switch to runlevel after 17 min of activity but just one time after cron reboot
I have a Linux arm device for which I've set a cron job to reboot the system periodically.
The system is based on busybox and uses a customized kernel version 4.1
The issue is that this specific device, 17 min after the cron job is correctly executed, switches to runlevel 6 which is the reboot level without any intervention from my software or other cron jobs, I'm starting to think that I have a possessed device .
I have the same image on hundreds of other devices, and none have the same behavior.
Has anyone ever faced a similar issue?
Maybe I changed something in the U-boot without notice, 'cause this device is the same that I've used for debugging my codes for a while.
